# Javascript Post Function to an existing Rest Api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, rest

For working reasons, i've to use for the first time RestFul Api, Json and NodeJS, to retrieve data from KairosDB, a NoSQL Database. [Here's the definition of the method to return datapoints with a Post function](https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/wiki/QueryMetrics)

What I understand is that I have to make a JSON with parameters selected by the user, and then send this JSON to the url above.

It was suggested me to use NodeJS, i've read from the official website, i've installed it and started a tutorial that learnt me to create a small webserver.

Anyway i'm totally stuck on the way of make a Post function to call those parameters.

Due to my experience, I have in mind how to do things above with a simple html page, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var myUrl="http://192.168.1.46:8080/api/v1/datapoints/query";
$.ajax({        
    url: myUrl ,
    data: {metrics: [{tags: {}, name: "AIENR",
      aggregators: [
        {
          name: "sum",
          sampling: {
            value: "1",
            unit: "milliseconds"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  cache_time: 0,
  start_absolute: 1328223600000,
  end_absolute: 1351983600000
},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('Error: '+e);
    }  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, the code above gives me an error: object Object and I don't understand how to implement this with Node JS and how to contact it to retrieve results. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should search whether there is a node.js driver/connector for your NoSQL database. If it exists and if it's stable - just use this.

Otherwise:

You could do it the hard way (use core modules like `http` and `https`), or use module like [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request).

Then, in node.js you would call your NoSQL database more or less like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/datapoints/query',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {some: "jsonfile"},
    timeout: 10000
}, function (err, response, body) {

    // error handling

    // take some values from body and send it to client

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately there isn't a driver or a connector for KairosDB.